# Angular UI Router: How to go to the same state with different $stateParam?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I am wondering how can I go to the same state, with different `$stateParam`?

I was trying to go with:

```
$state.go('^.currentState({param: 0})')
```

However, it was not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the params are second paramater of the `go()` method

```
$state.go('^.currentState', {param: 0})
```

#### [go(to, params, options)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go)

> Convenience method for transitioning to a new state. $state.go calls $state.transitionTo internally but automatically sets options to { location: true, inherit: true, relative: $state.$current, notify: true }. This allows you to easily use an absolute or relative to path and specify only the parameters you'd like to update (while letting unspecified parameters inherit from the currently active ancestor states).

Comment: Also, I found out that the following works: $state.go('.',{param: 0})

Comment: What does the `^.` mean?

Comment: @LeonGaban It is a short way how to say parent state.. without explicitly naming it. Check https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.$state - *`$state.go('^')` - will go to a parent state
`$state.go('^.sibling')` - will go to a sibling state*

Comment: Thanks! btw I'm running into a state navigation issue myself, mind a look see? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862998/how-to-send-object-from-1-state-into-another-state-with-ui-router

Answer (score 5):

You might want to use this piece of code:

```html
<a ui-sref=".({param: 0})"></a>
```

No need to use controller.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I wanted to reload the same state, but with different parameters. (`null` in this specific occurrence)

The situation is as follows: We have a website with different companies, each with their own branding page. You can visit other companies' pages and there's a menu entry to quickly visit your own.

A company's page is located under `/company/somecompanyid`, whereas your own page will be loaded when visiting `/company`. Without the addition of an id. Or `company_id: null` in code.

**The problem**
When you're viewing a random company's page, let's say `company/123456` and you click the designated menu entry to visit your own page, nothing would happen!
Ui-router believes you're on the same route and simply keeps you there.

**The solution**
Add the following to your template:
`<a ui-sref="company" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, inherit: false}" ... ></a>`

**What does it do?**
`reload: true` This will force your state to reload. But it'll copy your current route parameters. Which means your still seeing the other company's page.

`inherit: false` Setting the `inherit` property to `false` will force ui-router to use the params you provided. In my case, the companyId was `null` and user's personal page was loaded. Hurray!

You can find all ui-sref-options on the documentation pages. [ui-sref-options](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#options-1)

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to reload your state, you can also use ui-sref-opts. Passing in the `reload: true` option, will reload the current state.

`<a ui-sref-opts="{reload:true}" ui-sref="app.post.applicants">Applicants</a>`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is  ->

You can make 2 state with same controller and same html page and redirect one by one

PROS: No need to handle back history  and all works with the great flow

```
  .state('app.productDetails', {
         url: '/productDetails',
         cache: false,
         views: {
             'menuContent': {
                 templateUrl: 'src/products/productDetails/productDetails.html',
                 controller: 'ProductDetailsCtrl'
             }
         },
         params: {
             productID: 0,
             modelID: 0
         }
     })

    .state('app.modelDetails', {
        url: '/modelDetails',
        cache: false,
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'src/products/productDetails/productDetails.html',
                controller: 'ProductDetailsCtrl'
            }
        },
        params: {
            productID: 0,
            modelID: 0
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$state.go('.', {param: someId});
```